How can i insert total mean in pivot table columns?
I have the following data:

I would like to know the average score for each item for each subject.
So I used the pivot table function in Python.
However, the average for each evaluator is calculated instead of the overall average, so this needs to be calculated again.
I used the following code:
df_total_pv = pd.pivot_table(
    df_total,
    index='Subject',
    columns='Judge',
    values=['item1','item2','item3'],
    aggfunc='mean'
)


and the result was:

but I want to get a total mean,
like this:

How can I get this result?

Can you share the data as values and not picture please?
It's you don't use the "Judge" column, so why columns='Judge'?

You could use groupby:
df_total_pv = df_total.groupby('Subject')[['item1', 'item2', 'item3']].mean()

Worth noting that pivot_table uses groupby 'behind the scenes'
or you could use:
df_total_pv = pd.pivot_table(
    df_total,
    index='Subject',
    values=['item1','item2','item3'],
    aggfunc='mean'
)

which each give the result you expect

You could drop the Judge column before performing groupby and mean.
df_total_pv = df_total.drop(columns=['Judge']).groupby('Subject').mean()

Basically, the Judge column is dropped before hand, making it not needed to filter the columns for mean, instead we could use mean on every column.
